# Not able to click on "Home" Button Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

On [Website](http://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/index.php) when I login with Username: mercury and
PW: mercury and click on Submit button I go to Login Successfully page. Then I need to click on home button which is on the left side but i can't.

```
from telnetlib import EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\ChromeDriverExtracted\chromedriver")
driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element_by_name("userName").send_keys("mercury")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("mercury")
driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/font/a"))).click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an absolute xpath

```
/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/font/a
```

please use one of the text-based locator from below:

```
//a[text()='Home']
```

or with `LINK_TEXT` like this :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Home"))).click()
```

You can also use the below CSS selector:

```
a[href='index.php']
```

There are other ways as well to click,

**Code trial 1:**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Home']").click()
```

**Code trial 2:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Home']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Home']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Home']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: Error I get is AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'element_to_be_clickable'

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as ***Home*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Home"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.signin-btn.sbLoginBtn > span.btf-text"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Home']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Error I get is AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'element_to_be_clickable'